# Сайт не отдаёт на загрузку файл больше 8 кб

Tags: php

Имею динамический текст в файле index.php, который меняется в зависимости от utm меток.

Данный текст должен автоматически сохраняться в текстовом файле и отдаваться на скачивание пользователю (тобишь сразу при переходе на сайт).

Отдача реализована следующим образом:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_file_name.'test.txt');
echo $content;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при размере текста до 8 кб файл успешно скачивается как требуется. А при большем весе скачивается пустой файл на 0 байт.

Как решить данную проблему?

Код целиком:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_file_name.'test.txt');
echo $content;


$utm = $_GET['key'];
   if($utm == 'key1') {
   $multiTitle = 'Ключ1';
   }

elseif($utm == 'key2') {
   $multiTitle = 'Ключ2';
   }

else{
   $multiTitle = 'Неизвестно';
}

Тестовый текст, который автоматически сохраняется в txt файл с правильным ключом - <?php echo $multiTitle; ?>
```

Comment: Ошибок в этом коде я не вижу. А значит, ошибки в коде выше, которого нет. Добавьте весь код. Также напишите какие веб-сервера стоят до PHP кода - может быть там стоит увеличить лимиты.

Comment: @Total Pusher
Использую сервис Timeweb, дополнительно ничего не устанавливал, так что скорее всего используется стандартное ПО: Nginx 1.16 + Apache 2.4.
Код целиком добавил в вопрос.

Comment: А если какой-то файрволл провайдера? Типа защиты от dos-атак?

Comment: на сколько помню где-то ограничения выставляются, но точно не скажу php.ini или сам сервер настроить, больше склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Comment: @Qwertiy ♦ Раздал интернет с телефона ради интереса, результат такой же. Проблема скорее всего в настройке сайта.

Comment: На сервере файрволл, а не на компе...

Comment: @DaniilLoban в PHP нет ограничений на размер СКАЧИВАЕМОГО файла. Так что данное ограничение находится где-то ниже по уровню.

Comment: Такое впечатление что это размер какого-то буфера в который просто не влазит остальное содержимое, позже проверю и у себя

Comment: @DaniilLoban Это если вывод осуществляется через буфферизацию `семейство функций ob_*`.